# Verify if android app is install via Adwords

Tags: android, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

our marketing team is running adwords for our google store ad campaign. they wants to check if an app installation event is triggered when a user clicked on the advertised link or not. (probably like conversion tracking for installation via adwords). is there anyway we can do this?